# How to sync podcasts from iPod Classic to iTunes on other PC?

Tags: itunes, windows, podcasts, ipod-classic

I have a new Windows PC and copying the settings and iTunes folders from the old machine did not work.
I want to have the downloaded podcast episodes and the subscriptions that I have on my iPod Classic on the new PC.
Can I somehow sync them from the iPod to iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a tedious solution on the Internet:
Add all downloaded episodes to the new iTunes by copying the iTunes library and then select from the File menu "Add files to library". Go into each podcast's folder and select all files to add them to iTunes. Then iTunes will create the podcast with all these episodes, but you then have to subscribe to it again using the context menu on each podcast, so that it will be updated by iTunes.